# Differentiation of a summation function. Please advise

Tags: derivatives, summation, partial-derivative

Please help me understand the differentiation of this function.

$$P_L = \sum_{i=1}^{n_g}\sum_{j=1}^{n_g} P_iB_{ij}P_j~+~\sum_{i=1}^{n_g}B_{0i}P_i~+~B_{00}$$

What would the partial differentiation $\frac{\partial P_L}{\partial P_i}$ be?

My understanding is that it should be

$$\frac{\partial P_L}{\partial P_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n_g}\sum_{j=1}^{n_g} B_{ij}P_j~+~\sum_{i=1}^{n_g}B_{0i}$$

However, the book says

$$\frac{\partial P_L}{\partial P_i} = 2\sum_{j=1}^{n_g} B_{ij}P_j~+~B_{0i}$$

What am I missing please?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It is differentiating with respect to a particular i, while the i in the right hand side is a dummy variable. Try to differentiate with respect to $P_1$ and see what you get.

Comment: Yeah the confusion is probably that you've used $i$ as two distinct variables.

Comment: Split the summation into the case where $i\neq j$ and $i=j$. In the latter case, note that the derivative (where appropriate) is $2 P_i$. For the former case, note that any given index will appear once as $i$ and again as $j$.

Comment: Can you please split the summation and show me how the splits look like.